# I have added a delete Function , It is deleteing the row successfully but i want to delete from localstorage tooo in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I have added a delete Function , It is deleteing the row successfully but i want to delete from localstorage tooo in JavaScript
And Whenever user reload the page so it could be delete from localstorage alo so the book will be not appear
And i want to delete it from localstorage when function clicked, thats it

### JavaScript File

```
class Display {
    add(book) {
        console.log('Adding to UI');
        let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody')
        let uiString = `<tr class="tableBody" id="tableBody">
                            <td id="search">${book.name}</td>
                            <td>${book.author}</td>
                            <td>${book.type}</td>
                            <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="RemoveRow()"></td>
                        </tr>`;
        tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;

        // save the data to the browser's local storage -----
        const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
        // console.log(books);
        if (!books.some((oldBook) => oldBook.id === book.id)) books.push(book);
        localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(books));

    }
```

---

```
function RemoveRow(uid) {
    // event.target will be the input element.
    let td1 = event.target.parentNode; 
    let tr1 = td1.parentNode; 
    tr1.parentNode.removeChild(tr1);// the row to be removed
    window.localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(books));
}

$('tableBody').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
})
```

### HTML File

```
    <div id="table">

        <h1>Your Books</h1>
        <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Author</th>
                    <th scope="col">Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tableBody" id="tableBody"> </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

Comment: But How should i remove from localstorage

Comment: Why are you using a weird mix of JS and jQuery?

Comment: ignore that jquery that would have comment out

Answer (score 0):

In my view, I guess when you filter books based on id and then set them again to the local storage, it will solve your problem.

```
const newBooks= books.filter(book=> book.id !== idThatYouNeedToDelete)
```

localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(newBooks));

Comment: Its Not Working